# Asp.Net Core - could not found view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVzqb.png)I had written simple code in controller's action method.

```
var employee = new Employee { ID = 1, Name = "Mark Upston" };
return new View(employee);
```

Getting below error 
The type or namespace name **'View'** could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Included the below references

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor;
```

Comment: If you posted the *error* and the *code* instead of a screenshot, the problem would be obvious. You gave the *namespace* the same name as the Controller class. The compiler complains about that. The obvious solution is to change the *namespace* name to eg Controllers. Or you can use the full name of the Controller type, including the namespace

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you got the idea to use `new`.. but as far as I am aware you can't `new` a function.  `View()` is a function.

Comment: Removed the new key word. Even though the View function is not resolved.

Comment: @RajeshreeNevare: Does your controller derive from the `Controller` class? It would really help if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets.

Comment: Not able to find controller class.

Comment: Have created an empty project. Asp.net core web application. Added MVC controller, but getting the below error :

Comment: @JonSkeet - I have added the screen shot of complete code.

Comment: @RajeshreeNevare post the *code* and the *error*, not the screenshot. Screenshots can't be compiled. Although the error message is very clear. You used the same name for the namespace as the base Controller type. Don't do that. Change the namespace to Controller*s*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Tried with that as well. Changed the namespace to Controllers. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @RajeshreeNevare no you aren't. If you did, you'd get either no error, or another error saying that `Controller` can't be found. Visual Studio even offers to **fix this for you**. Did you click on the suggestions? Most likely it's offering to add the correct namespace. Post the code and the actual error. Something that others can copy and check.

Comment: @RajeshreeNevare the code clearly comes from the MVC template, which *works*. It was *modified* though: at the very least someone change the namespace to `Controller`. Some `using` clauses were also removed probably. Either rever the changes that caused the problem, or simply delete the project and create a new one.

Comment: @RajeshreeNevare or create a new project and simply compare the files to see what's missing.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos    - please find below code for controller. Please note I have created new empty project. If I use MVC template its working fine.

Comment: HomeController.cs using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using App3.Models;
namespace App3.Controller
{    public class HomeController : Controller
    {        public ViewResult Index()
        {             var employee = new Employee { ID = 1, Name = "Mark Upston" };            return View(employee);        }    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue. Just used full class name instead of only controller. i.e. -Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
see below code. But I think it should also work with only controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using App3.Models;

namespace App3.Controller
{
    public class HomeController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
    {
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var employee = new Employee { ID = 1, Name = "Mark Upston" };
            return View(employee);
        }
    }
}
```